# How to get certain part from widget

Tags: plugins, widgets

I want to use only some part of the widget.

I have multisite network so to link the posts and pages I am using a plugin called Multilingual Press which also comes with widget to switch sites.

Now I have registered a widget area on my header and I want only the part:

ENGLISH FINNISH form the widget, but it is coming with all the divs and title and everything how can I get the only link part from the widget and place is on my desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot separate the markup from the output in this widget. The links are built from the result of `mlp_show_linked_elements()`, so you can use that to create the elements with a custom function or a new widget.

This will print the links to all connected pages:

```
mlp_show_linked_elements(
    array(
        'link_text'         => 'text',
        'show_current_blog' => TRUE
    )
);
```

You can add a parameter `'echo' => FALSE` to use the result as a value for a variable:

```
$links = mlp_show_linked_elements(
    array(
        'link_text'         => 'text',
        'show_current_blog' => TRUE,
        'echo'              => FALSE
    )
);
// do something with the links …
echo $links;
```